# jquery drag and drop ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

html:

```
<div id="divDroppable">
    <div id="element1"></div>
    <div id="element2"></div>
    <div id="element3"></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
  $("#element1").draggable();
  $("#element1").droppable({
  drop: function() { alert('dropped'); }
```

drop function alert is not fire where is my mistake? i want a loop which perform each elemt of div must be dragged but unable to loop between them bcz each id is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I notice is you have a syntax error. The line isn't complete.

```
$("#element1").draggable();
$("#element1").droppable({
    drop: function() { alert('dropped'); }
});
```

If you want to do the same to each element you could do something like this:

```
$("#divDroppable div").each(function() {
    var id = this.id
    $(this).draggable().droppable({
        drop: function() { alert('dropped ' + id); }
    });
});
```

Comment: no no that is my mistake to post a question.its not mistake in a real code.

Comment: are you loading the code after the DOM is ready? (e.g. inside a `$(function() {` /* code */ `});` block?

Comment: thanks @redEvo i got a solun.i load a code after a DOM and got a solun.Thanks a lot